# Scene Organization, When does it get too big?

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling an entire downtown section of a city - the buildings roads, trees, everything.

But I'm also thinking of using it as a terrain/world in a videogame, where I'm using Unity.  So right now I'm modeling several buildings all in Blender, and I've fooled around with importing them into Unity to make sure it works and it does, but the real question is, as this grows larger, and I have dozens, maybe hundreds of buildings, should I have the buildings in separate Blender files and then combine them in Unity? or Combine them in another Blender file?  Right now I have several buildings wall to wall in one Blender file, and I've got 2 other Blender files with individual buildings from another part of downtown that are disconnected.

Maybe I should keep the individual buildings in individual files, and also have a copy of the buildings in another Blender file? But that would be a pain to update every time I change something.

I like how when I have my Blender models as assets in Unity, I can update them in Blender and it automatically updates them in Unity. Is that probably the best way to organize this?

Thanks for any comments advice or feedback.

Here's a pic of what I got btw:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated question. The main things you need to go on are the Principles of Unity project construction, 3D assets creation and optimization, project hierarchy, and the Why question.

If you are new to Unity, it is better to learn some basics, it will save time in the future. First of all, Unity is a good and simple engine for creating mobile games. Its OK for LowPoly but if we are talking about cool architectural visualization of a part of a whole city, it is better to look at Unreal Engine 5 with its nanite system.

When working with 3D Assets, it's worth thinking about where we are now. If we are at the stage of forming a concept, it is good to have one file in which we can compare several buildings, cars, roads and other elements that will fill our scene for the purpose of compositional similarity (such as gamma, scale of objects, the nature of forms). All elements should look like parts of a whole.

During the Asset Creation phase, we need to separate all the models into different files. This will help set the tone of the project hierarchy, not to overload one file, and thus accelerate the work, because in the course of the project each .blend file will acquire textures, references, pre-renderers, and it is desirable to keep it all in separate folders so as not to make a mess in the project.

I have already noted above that it is important to keep the project hierarchy, everything must be organized so that even when the project acquires a large number of files it remains easy to read. And of course if someone wants to join the development it will be easier for him to get up to speed.

Perhaps the most important question to ask is "Why". What is the main goal of the project, to make work in the portfolio, to develop skills in 3D modeling and working in Unity, to get fun with friends in multiplayer, to put the first game in the store, etc.
For all of the above reasons, any experienced 3D artist or developer will advise going from small to big. Big projects look appealing and ambitious, but the cost of a mistake due to ignorance or even a simple change of intent or concept will cost a lot more than if you tried to make one beautiful quarter, or make a story of a single house in the form of a diorama.

As usual: I wrote the answer in a hurry, I will add examples and details in the evening.

Comment: Daumn, this is so well put together :). Could've used this advice when starting my first big project :))